# Android TTS Thread Issue

Tags: android, multithreading, text-to-speech

I'm working on Android project which returns text result as TTS service.
It's my first time on Android so I was doing all the jobs at main thread.
It doesn't give any problem since I tried to get TTS in three different languages.
English, which is Locale language of testboard was fine. When I tried to test Korean and Chinese TTS just jumped to next step and give log message.

> W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
>   I/Choreographer: Skipped 278 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

So I tried to do TTS at different thread.

MainActivity.java onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            capture();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    KorHan.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            processImageKor(img);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

Detect.java onCreate()

```
ttsKor = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Locale kor = new Locale("ko", "");
                int result = ttsKor.setLanguage(kor);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Intent ins = new Intent();
                    ins.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    startActivity(ins);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Detect.java processImageKor()

```
 public void processImageKor(Bitmap img) {
    String lang = "kor";
    // get text from another function works successfull

    TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txtView.setText(outText);

    ttsKor.setPitch(1.0f);
    ttsKor.setSpeechRate(1.0f);
    ttsKor.speak(txtView.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "ttsKor");
}
```

After I changed code like this, I'm pretty sure doing TTS at different thread, still gives same log message and even english tts doesn't works too. I've checked Detect.java oncreate TTS was successful without log message. Skipped frames log message only appears after tts.speak(); ends but tts.speak() speaks nothing.

Should I create TTS service in Thread? Or did I do something wrong with making thread?
Any opinion must be very helpful for me.

Comment: I believe those are two unrelated issues, and `speak failed: not bound to TTS engine` is the one causing your problem.  The frame skipping would be good to solve too but if it's not causing a crash can probably be temporarily ignored.  However before you release the app, I would test with the latest Android version (on an emulator if you don't have a device) to make sure there are no problems there.  As to the TTS I don't know anything about that so can't help you with specifics.

Comment: Thanks for comment @nasch. Before the speak failed message "I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.svox.pico"  showed up. That's why I think tts engine was fine. But every time I launch the app "pico tts has stopped" message occurred. It really confusing me.

Comment: You have put effort into this question, but there is simply far too much going on... too many potential problems... unknown factors... not enough code given... in order for me (or presumably anyone) to be able to help.  I would suggest breaking your project down into smaller, independent working parts.  I do know these facts, however: 1) it should never be necessary to create a tts on a separate thread. 2) Creating and manipulating views from a background thread will be problematic. 3)The PICO tts engine is flawed and not guaranteed to work on Android API 20 or higher from my experience.

Comment: @BooberBunz Maybe it's bit late to give appreciate to you. Just after I finished this question I just happened to try it on another device and it works perfect. It's all fault of PICO TTS engine. I just know PICO TTS engine doesn't works nice but thanks to your answer I know why now.
And also I even didn't think of other problems could exist cause error message keeps talking about Thread. Really helpful for my future work.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the note.